# Cancel a running SQL Server Reporting Services report subscription?

Tags: reporting-services, reportingservices-2005

I've created a Reporting Services report and set it to run on a subscription.  (SQL Server 2005, if it makes a difference.)

Unfortunately, it looks like I've made some sort of error in the parameters, and it seems to have stalled, but it isn't actually failing, just sitting on "0 processed".

I want to cancel it to fix the error, but I can't figure out how.  Stopping/restarting the services seems to make no difference.

What do I need to do to stop it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A subscription is a SQL-Server Agent job, and is given a GUID as a title. Check the SQL-Server Agent job history, and if necessary stop the job.

If you have more than one subscription, check this link for a useful View on which jobs correspond to which subscription.

http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic254010-150-1.aspx